# How to process an HTML file to reference fingerprinted assets?

Tags: svelte, rollupjs

I have a svelte app bundled with rollup in which I want the generated assets (`bundle.js` and `bundle.css`) to be fingerprinted with a hash those files references in the `index.html`.

I managed to do the first part easily with the `entryFileNames`:

```
  {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
      sourcemap: true,
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'app',
      entryFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
      dir: 'public/build'
    },
    // ...
```

But replacing the name of the fingerprinted asset (say, `main.1a2b3c4d.js`) in the `index.html` is the complex part.

I planned on having a `src/index.html` containing some markers like `<script defer src='<% jsBundle %>'></script>` and some rollup configuration that allowed me to replace those markers with the name of the hashed files, generating a `public/index.html` that contains `<script defer src='/public/main.1a2b3c4d.js'></script>`.

I'm not sure of how to process an HTML file (rollup doesn't seem to allow entry files to be anything but JS files). And even after that I'd need to know how to find the fingerprinted name of the assets to do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any existing npm modules that can do this for you, but you can *"easily"* write your own rollup plugin for this. [Rollup Plugin Development](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#plugin-development)

The hook you would be looking for is [writeBundle](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#writebundle) this is a hook that runs *after* all your files have been written, and, as the documentation suggests it will give you a list of all files being generated.

Within this hook you can then use something like [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) to open up your `index.html` and replace the placeholders with the generated files.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself, but it doesn't look overly complicated. You could use this hook to generate the hash itself as well, combining these two would actually make a nice package if you feel like contributing to the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
assetFileNames: `[name].[hash].[ext]`
```